Control M Dynamic job variables according to order date
We have some embedded script jobs that are deployed with calendars in Control M. Those jobs are orders and run as calendars are defined. Those embedded script jobs need some parameters to run for now we fetch these arguments using LIBMEMSYM and deriving variable name using Smart folder name, job name and order date. Are there any way to tie arguments with calendar date. we have specific values for these arguments on different order days.
